# configuration configuration on LWRP

Tags: chef-infra

I'm using this configuration provider in order to configure my elasticsearch:

```
elasticsearch_configure 'my_elasticsearch' do
  path_home     "/opt/elasticsearch"
  path_data     data_location
  ...
end
```

`data_location` value is picked up from:

```
data_location = node['living']['elastic']['data_location']
```

Nevertheless, this attribute is not setted on my current environment `dev`:

```
{
  "living": {
    "elastic": {
      "version": "5.4.0",
      "cluster": "cluster-dev",
      "node": "node1",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 9201,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

So, according whether `data_location` is `nil` or not I need to set it on `elasticsearch_configure` or not...

I've absolutly no idea how to get it. Any ideas?

Comment: `path_data data_location unless data_location.nil?` should do (ruby `unless` inlined syntax) (I hope I got your requirements right, it's not really clear what you're after at all, a pseudo code or illustration of what you wish to obtain would help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is not required and has a [default value](https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch/blob/master/libraries/resource_configure.rb#L15) so as long as you're happy with that default, just don't set it.